# Pydev code browsing?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I've been -trying- to use pydev to do some python (can't say I'm having good times so far). I finally got code completion working for the libraries I'm using, but I'm still wondering about a couple of things...

So the library I'm using is called orange. Say I call the function orange.MakeRandomIndices2, but I'm not sure how it works... I want to see the source code of this function, or at least some useful information as to it's usage.. Is there any way to do this from my ide?

Also while debugging, I might want to do just the same.. step into that function and debug it internally... I cannot seem to be able to do this and I just don't understand WHY seeing I have the source code on my hard disk.

Thanks.
JC

Answer (score 2):

When you hover your cursor over a function or class, Pydev should show you the docstring. Click on the function/class, then press F3, and it will take you to the definition of that function/class. If that is not happening, you probably have not configured Pydev correctly. Look over the documentation again, making sure you have done all the steps. If that still does not work, the Pydev author is very active and helpful on the pydev mailinglists.

When you are debugging code, F5 will step into a function. F6 will step over.